# Why do I get a clang error in the following code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <climits>
#include <set>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
#define ll long long
#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair

int main (void)
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,60,70,8,50,20};
    int mseh = 0;
    int mssf = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int e = 10;
    while ( i < e )
    {
        mseh = mseh + arr[i];
        if (mseh < 0)
            mseh = 0;
        if (mssf < mseh)
                mssf = mseh;
        i++;
    }
    cout<<mseh<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I have written the above code, that only calculates the maximum non negative sub-array in a given array. When I try to compile the above, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [1] Error 1
```

This error is very cryptic and I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong in the code. Thanks

Comment: At least use a typedef instead of a preprocessor macro. Don't "define types" like that.

Comment: How are you trying to compile it ? what command are you using ?

Comment: Vaviable and function names should be clear and meaningful. Write code for the next reader and to be easily understood, that will also reduce errors.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have not linked a proper Standard Library implementation like libstdc++. Under most circumstances you should have one linked for you by default but clearly something has gone wrong here. The exact cause will be entirely environmental.